# RSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to solve a recurrence equation where all three parameters of the function k are integer and between 0 and n.

```
RSolve[{k[n, xp, x] == k[n - 1, n - 1, x]/k[n - 1, xp, n-1], k[0, xp, x] == k0[xp, x]}, k[n, xp, x], {n, xp, x}]
```

Unfortunately, I get an error for this function:

```
RSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.
```

It seems to have a problem with the fact that, on right hand side of the equation, I use n-1 as second argument. This is correct but Mathematica does not like that.

Do you have a solution for this problem?  Please note that the equation that I have written is a dummy equation for showing the problem, the actual equation is more complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Silvio

Comment: looks ill posed to me.

Answer (score 1):

retracting my ill posed comment, we can solve this by hand:

```
ClearAll[k]
k[n_, xp_, x_] := k[n - 1, n - 1, x]/k[n - 1, xp, n - 1]
k[0, x_, xp_] = c0[{x, xp}]
```

which gives results for numeric n:

```
k[5, y, z] -> (c0[{0, z}] c0[{4, 0}])/(c0[{0, 4}] c0[{y, 0}])
```

by inspection the generic result is:

```
k[n, xp, x] == 
    k[0, 0, x]/ k[0, 0, n - 1] 
     ( k[0, n - 1, 0] /  k[0, xp, 0]   )^((-1)^(n + 1))
```

so you need initial values for all those k[0,v,0] and k[0,0,v]

I'm not that familiar with RSolve to say if there is some trick to coax it to generate this automatically.